# Unable to see map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS but used to ArcGIS.  I am working my way through the tutorial and have downloaded a map from earth explorer - following all the instructions.  The map is in the left hand panel and the co-ordinates are visible. A thumbnail is showing in properties.

I have tried zoom to image but no map appears.

I cannot continue with the tutorial until I get the map!

Comment: the layer is checked

Comment: That did it! - so what is CRS

Comment: Will post the above comments as an answer for the convenience of others.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) is the **same** for the layer you want to view **and** the projected CRS.

To give a brief description, a CRS is used to project objects and locations on a map. There are 2 types of CRS ( both quoted from this [source](http://www.ga.gov.au/webtemp/image_cache/GA20953.pdf)):

- Geographic coordinate system which contains locations defined in terms of the position on a globe using latitude and longitude values.
- Projected coordinate system which contains locations defined using Cartesian x, y coordinates on a flat, two-dimensional surface.